# node.js: save object whose value changed inside a conditional callback

Tags: node.js

I have the following code to save a profile, password is only updated if old password and new password are provided. Old password is checked inside the model, so i'm getting the check value inside the callback.

The problem with the following code is that i have to call user.save inside the callback and after the callback.
What is the best way to refactor this, thx

```
  user.firstName = req.body.firstName;
  user.lastName = req.body.lastName;

  if (req.body.password)
    if (req.body.newPassword)
    //we want to change password
      user.comparePassword(req.body.password, function(err, isMatch) {
      if (!isMatch) {
        return res.status(401).send({
          message: 'Mot de passe actuel invalide'
        });

      }
      user.password = req.body.newPassword;
      user.save(function(err) {
        if (err)
          res.status(500).send({
            message: "Une erreur est survenue lors de la mise à jour du profil"
          });
        var profile = {
          displayName: getDisplayName(user),
          pictureUrl: user.pictureUrl || config.defaultProfilePic,
        };
        profile.lastName = user.lastName;
        profile.firstName = user.firstName;
        res.send(profile);
      });
    });

  user.save(function(err) {
    if (err)
      res.status(500).send({
        message: "Une erreur est survenue lors de la mise à jour du profil"
      });
    var profile = {
      displayName: getDisplayName(user),
      pictureUrl: user.pictureUrl || config.defaultProfilePic,
    };
    profile.lastName = user.lastName;
    profile.firstName = user.firstName;
    res.send(profile);
  });
```

Edit: i created a function saveUser(user, res) which i call twice.
is this the best solution?

Comment: first, are you sure that you are not forgetting some parenthesis? Also, I am not understanding why you are doing to user.save?

Answer (score 3):

Why not create a "saveUser" function called either after the check of the password or in the other case:

```
function saveUser(user,res){
  user.save(function(err) {
     if (err)
       res.status(500).send({
       message: "Une erreur est survenue lors de la mise à jour du profil"
     });
     var profile = {
      displayName: getDisplayName(user),
      pictureUrl: user.pictureUrl || config.defaultProfilePic,
    };
    profile.lastName = user.lastName;
    profile.firstName = user.firstName;
    res.send(profile);
  });
}

user.firstName = req.body.firstName;
user.lastName = req.body.lastName;

if (req.body.password) && (req.body.newPassword) {
  //we want to change password
  user.comparePassword(req.body.password, function(err, isMatch) {
    if (!isMatch) {
      return res.status(401).send({
        message: 'Mot de passe actuel invalide'
      });
    }
    user.password = req.body.newPassword;
    saveUser(user,res);
  });
} else {
 saveUser(user,res);
}
```

Another option would be to use promise (using Q library)

```
Q().then(checkPasswordChange).then(saveUser);
```

but I am not an expert in promise and no time to write the exact code...

Comment: Thx tomsoft, yes that's what i did, is this the best solution?

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand the question (and if I don't feel free to correct me):

You need to call user.save, then then send the response (res.send) and then user.save again(?).

If this is what you want I would take a look at [async](https://github.com/caolan/async). It will let you run async code in series (async.series)

i.e.

```
async.series([
    function(){ ... },
    function(){ ... },
    function(){ ... }
]);
```

Where the first function could be user.save and then a second function could be to send the response and the third function could be to user.save again.

You can add any number of function into the array and they will be executed from first to last. It works well with async code because the next function will not execute until the previous function has completed.

Hope this helps! Be sure to let me know if you need any clarification!